# Sweet Alert is not working inside ajax calls in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, alert, sweetalert

Sweet Alert - https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

I have imported Sweet Alert using CDN inside my base html file:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried to use Sweet Alert inside ajax calls in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'deliveryupdate/'+barcode2+'/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                barcode: barcode2,
                owner: owner2,
                mobile: mobile2,
                address: address2,
                atype: atype2,
                status: "Gecia Authority Approved",
                statusdate: today,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(){
              console.log("success log");
              swal("Success!","Asset request has been approved","success");
            },
            error: function(){
              console.log('error', arguments)
              swal("Error!","Some error occurred","error");
            }
        });
```

This is not working, even though there are successful changes in the database, the error function is executing instead of success function, and the error sweet alert flashes for a mini-second and vanishes. The console shows error log.

But if I change sweet alert to normal browser alert, it works perfectly.( but that too only in Chrome, not in firefox )

Its working perfectly when I replace swal() with alert().  (only in Chrome though)

I don't want the normal browser alert, I need a good looking alert like Sweet Alert. In my other templates where there are no ajax calls and simple alerts, sweet alert is working fine with no problems.

Please Help.

edit: Adding views function:

```
def gecia_ass_del(request):
    deliverylist = Delivery.objects.filter(status='Added to Delivery List')
    context = {'deliverylist': deliverylist}
    return render(request, 'gecia_ass_del.html', context)
```

Just to be clear the context in the views is not related to my ajax calls.

Comment: Please provide `views` that gives response to your ajax call.

Comment: Sounds like you are making request inside a form event listener and not preventing default form submit

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I have added in the question.

Comment: @charlietfl i have 2 buttons - approve and reject. I am executing different ajax calls depending on which button is clicked. I dont have a form submit button as such.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the callback function swal by Swal.fire